# Set texture to colored CC3MeshNode

Tags: ios, textures, cocos3d

First I set color of material to the node:

```
CC3MeshNode *node = [self.modelNode getMeshNodeNamed:nodeName];
CC3Material *material = [CC3Material material];
material.color = [CCColor colorWithUIColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:color]];
node.material = material;
node.visible = YES;
```

Later I need to fill this node with texture. And I can't

```
CC3Texture *texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile:@"texture.png"];
material.texture = texture;
node.material = material;
```

or

```
CC3Texture *texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile:@"texture.png"];
[node.material addTexture:texture]
```

or

```
CC3Texture *texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile:@"texture.png"];
node.material.color = [CCColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0];
[node.material addTexture:texture];
```

or

```
node.material = nil;
CC3Material *material = [CC3Material material];
node.material = material;
[node.material addTexture:texture];
```

returns white node with no texture.

But setting texture to the node at the begining works:

```
CC3MeshNode *node = [self.modelNode getMeshNodeNamed:nodeName];
CC3Texture *texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile:@"texture.png"];
[node.material addTexture:texture];
node.visible = YES;
```

Any idea how to apply texture to the node after setting its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using a shader that does not support textures.

If you are allowing **Cocos3D** to automatically select shaders for you, it will take certain aspects of your node into consideration when choosing the shaders. One of the primary aspects that determines which shaders to use is whether the node has a texture.

**Cocos3D** selects shaders either when you explicitly invoke the `selectShaders` method, or the first time the node is rendered. Once shaders have been initially selected, they are not automatically reselected if something on the node changes.

You can cause **Cocos3D** to select new shaders for your node by invoking `removeShaders` on your node, and then either invoking `selectShaders` again, or waiting until the node is rendered again.

An alternate would be to specifically assign your own shaders, that can accommodate all of the changes you will be making to your node.

Comment: Thank you Bill! Removing and selecting Shaders is working.

Comment: May you please give example of assign own shaders or maybe there is a way to create shader that may support both color and texture to switch them (showing one or another) later?

Comment: The `CC3DemoMashUp addFog` method contains an example of loading a specific pair of vertex and fragment shaders and applying them to a specific node.